# How does this function work exactly?

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand this scope exercise that I came across this [site's exercise](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-javascript/scope/scope.cfm). How exactly is `function doMultiplication` being called within `function writeIt`? Every time I try to figure out this seemingly simple exercise, I get cross-eyed. Can you break it down to explain how this one works, please? Thanks in advance.

```js
function writeIt(numTimes, multiple) {
  function doMultiplication(val, multiple) {
    i = val * multiple;
    return i;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
    document.write(doMultiplication(i, multiple) + ' ');
  }
}

writeIt(5, 2);
```

EDIT - here's my understanding of what's going on so it can be clarified what I'm not understanding here ...

So, with the writeIt(5, 2) function, it means that 2 is being multiplied to val? But what is val here?

I get the for equation, and how numTimes is 5 ... I think I'm being thrown off by the val part?

Comment: what do you mean how? it's inside document.write()

Comment: @lascort, wrote in an edit, a clumsy way of trying to explain my misunderstanding ...

Comment: val is i. Not sure, what the question is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Calling `writeIt(5,2);` following things happen -

`writeIt(5,2)` here `numTimes` = 5 & `multiple` = 2.

Now according to function declaration it moves to `for` loop -

```
for (let i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
    document.write(doMultiplication(i, multiple) + ' ');
}
```

TO -

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //document.write(doMultiplication(0, 2) + ' ');
    //document.write(doMultiplication(1, 2) + ' ');
    //document.write(doMultiplication(2, 2) + ' ');
    //document.write(doMultiplication(3, 2) + ' ');
    //document.write(doMultiplication(4, 2) + ' ');
}
```

Now we move to -

```
function doMultiplication(val, multiple) {
    i = val * multiple;
    return i;
}
```

Which is called from the for loop -

```
    //document.write(doMultiplication(0, 2) + ' ');
```

So doMultiplication(0, 2) => 0*2 => return 0; => 0 + ' ';

```
    //document.write(doMultiplication(1, 2) + ' ');
```

So doMultiplication(1, 2) => 1*2 => return 2; => 2 + ' ';

```
    //document.write(doMultiplication(2, 2) + ' ');
```

So doMultiplication(2, 2) => 2*2 => return 4; => 4 + ' ';

```
    //document.write(doMultiplication(3, 2) + ' ');
```

So doMultiplication(3, 2) => 3*2 => return 6; => 6 + ' ';

```
    //document.write(doMultiplication(4, 2) + ' ');
```

So doMultiplication(4, 2) => 4*2 => return 8; => 8 + ' ';

Answer (score 1):

`writeIt()` takes two parameters - `5` corresponds to how many times the function should run, and `2` corresponds to the multiple. Essentially, you're going to list the multiples of `2` five times.

`function doMultiplication(val, multiple)` is a [**nested** function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Nested_functions_and_closures) - it takes the same `multiple` parameter as `writeIt()`, along with the `i` from the `for` loop. Essentially, this function multiples the target number by the index passed in by the upcoming `for` loop.

Next up is `for (let i = 0; i < numTimes; i++)`. `let` is the ES6 equivalent of `var` (but with enclosing block-level scope); it simply sets up a new variable. This variable `i` starts at `0`, and is looped over until it is equal to the number of times that the function should run (`5`). For each of the iterations of this loops, it runs the `doMultiplication()` function, passing the index as the value to multiply by. The output is written to the page with `document.write()`.

Finally, `writeIt(5, 2);` simply **calls** the `writeIt()` function, and passes in the two parameters. Because it is not within a function itself, it gets executed as soon as the page is loaded.

The output is `0 2 4 6 8` because the `i` of the `for` loop starts at `0`, so that's where you start multiplying from.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Just to add, let is not only an equivalent as it gives you block scoping which is an important distinction to consider

Comment: Yep; I updated my answer to state that it gives enclosing block-level scope :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge, thank you for the nested function link, and your explanation! I appreciate you taking the time to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure about your question. But I will try to answer my best. 
Val is what is being passed from for loop ie i. So (val = i ).
It can be better looked by printing console statements rather than just writing it on browser. May be below snippet will help

```
function writeIt(numTimes, multiple) {
  function doMultiplication(val, multiple) {
    console.log('val is ', val);
    const i = val * multiple;
    console.info ('i after manipulation ', i);
    return i;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
    console.log('i is ', i);
    console.log(doMultiplication(i, multiple) + ' ');
   }
}

writeIt(5, 2);
```

One more thing, you should probably do is to make i a block scoped variable, rather than just having it a global variable.

Hope this helps.

Happy Learning

Vatsal

Comment: thank you for the console.log view. It was interesting looking at that! Appreciate you taking the time to explain it.